# Hibernate SchemaExport doesn't generate sql script

Tags: java, hibernate, schemaexport

Could anybody please help me and give an idea why the code below doesn't generate SQL creation script?
Hibernate version is 5.2.9.Final.
I tried different approaches, used exact class names, package location, connection to an existing database but unfortunately, no one of them works for me.
All code snippets I found on the internet looks like my one.

```
Class<PostgreSQL95Dialect> dialect = PostgreSQL95Dialect.class;

        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySetting(Environment.DIALECT, dialect)
            .build();

        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(registry);

        Set<Class<?>> entities = new Reflections("").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
        entities.forEach(e -> metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(e.getClass()));

        System.out.println(String.format("entities : %d", entities.size()));

        Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();

        new SchemaExport()
            .setFormat(true)
            .setDelimiter(";")
            .setOutputFile(String.format("ddl_%s.sql ", dialect.getSimpleName()))
            .execute(EnumSet.of(TargetType.STDOUT, TargetType.SCRIPT), SchemaExport.Action.BOTH, metadata);

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
```

The result of code execution is below

```
    Apr 27, 2017 7:26:43 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
entities : 144
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@5b239d7d
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Apr 27, 2017 7:26:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@74455848'
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found a root of evil :)

I created a test Entity and tried to generate script only for it and the code worked!
So the only possible place with a mistake is in getting classes with the help of reflection. And shame on me, how inattentive I was.
Instead of writing

```
entities.forEach(e -> metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(e.getClass()));
```

I need this

```
entities.forEach(e -> metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(e));
```

First one will always give

```
class java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

there is configuration issue of hibernate check again configuration of  hibernate.refer below code for sample.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">explorecalifornia</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc123</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I already tried using a connection to an existing database, checked it once again, it doesn't help.:( Also there are many examples over the internet without using a connection to a database.